# Laravel 4 plug-in system

Tags: php, plugins, laravel, laravel-4

I looking for some plugin structure for Laravel based applications.

For example a forum software, a cms or a e-commerce application can benefit from a plugin structure.

My question is what is the best way to implement this plugin system so that third party plugins can extend the application. The main issue is that it should be dynamically extendible and users should be able to install these plugins easily without messing with the app code.

This question also extends to themes but thats another question. Any ideas?

Comment: You may be interested in [Package Development](http://laravel.com/docs/packages)

Comment: There are many different ways to do that. Some have been outlined on Stackoverflow in similar questions if you keep away the Laravel 4 detail. If you want to study a review of multiple concepts found in different systems with their pros and cons discussed, here is a talk that covers multiple of them: [Modular application architecture - Confoo.ca 2012](http://qafoo.com/talks/12_03_confoo_modular_application_architecture.pdf) ([via](http://qafoo.com/resources/presentations.html))

Answer (score 2):

Laravel is a *framework*, not a *CMS* like Wordpress or Joomla, so plugin system that fits everybody may be quite hard to create as Laravel can be used in many ways, but I can really see the benefit of easy packages in some contexts.

The Packagist has been already mentioned and it doesn't solve *directly* your problem but how about:

1. Find good usable packages from Packagist for the purposes you need
2. Define common plugin architecture (common API for binding things together, installer, package format, migration, updates etc) on top of Packagist packages
3. Create installer that fetches packages via Packagist/Composer and adds sets sane default settings and configuration for the packages and integrates them into the defined plugin architecture
4. Document and plan this really well and the others will soon follow

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused about the question, but I believe what you are looking for is already implemented in Laravel 4.  They are just called Packages, and can be found at http://www.packagist.org and easily installed and autoloaded into your application using Composer.

Comment: This approach may be well suited for a developer who wants to add functionality to the software. But when a user who is administering a site wants to add a plugin to site this approach is complicated. It should be as simple as adding a plugin from a panel and enabling or disabling it. What I would like to know is how to best integrate this using Laravel.